# PopupControlExtender with an updatepanel : problem with chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:Panel ID="CreateGroupPanel" runat="server" 
           CssClass="style10" Visible="True" >
                <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" 
                                          runat="server">
                </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
....
</ asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp: Panel>

<asp:Button ID="Btn_CreateGroupPopUp " 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Create Group" 
            Width="109px" />
<asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server"
                          DynamicServicePath=""
                          Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" 
                          TargetControlID="Btn_CreateGroupPopUp" 
                          PopupControlID="CreateGroupPanel">
</asp:PopupControlExtender>
```

here the panel is popup when button btn_CreateGroupPopUp is clicked. It works fine with internet explorer, but when I open the website in chrome, the pop up comes and then the page refreshes automatically and the pop up is closed. What is the problem with this, I don’t have any time or meta refresh in my page.

Comment: do you have any JavaScript in your page? can you show it?

Comment: Yes i have this in my page     <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some research and I have found out that you should have something like this to have UpdatePanel working with webkit (which is the engine of Safari and Chrome):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Safari3AjaxHack.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>


Sys.Browser.WebKit = {}; //Safari 3 is considered WebKit
if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'WebKit/' ) > -1 )
{
  Sys.Browser.agent = Sys.Browser.WebKit;
  Sys.Browser.version = parseFloat( navigator.userAgent.match(/WebKit\/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1]);
  Sys.Browser.name = 'WebKit';
}
```

you can check many links on the internet about UpdatePanel not working in chrome or safari, also I believe I saw similar questions here in SO...

http://forums.asp.net/p/1252014/2898429.aspx

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/10/Gotcha-WebKit-%28Safari-3-and-Google-Chrome%29-Bug-with-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx